# VB.NET date format

Tags: vb.net, date, format

How do I replace 2014-12-27 with the current date in the statement

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from LateComersReport where PDate = '2014-12-27'", conn)

or how can I have the date in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'in the statement

Dim Tday As Date = Date.Today

Answer (score 2):

First, a date has no format, it has only a value. A date-string can have a format.

Second, always use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation if you build your sql query. That prevents sql-injection or conversion/locatization issues. And always pass the correct type(date is this case) instead of letting the database interpret your argument.

```
Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from LateComersReport where PDate = @PDate", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PDate" , SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date.Today ' or SqlDbType.DateTime '
    ' .. '
End Using
```

Comment: @rajan: if it solved your question acaccept it. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your SQL query to this:

```
"Select * from LateComersReport where PDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())"
```

A few things I'd like to point out: date variables, whether in SQL or in .NET, do not *have* formats.  Formatting is only useful/relevant when you are talking about displaying a date, i.e. as a string in a report or in a UI.  You shouldn't care how a date is displayed when it's a date value being used in your code.

Also, as a habit, you should use parameters in your SQL statements whenever applicable as opposed to concatenating strings together.  For example, if you were to insert your own date value in the query instead of using SQL's built-in `GETDATE()` function, you would do this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from LateComersReport where PDate = @MyDateValue", conn)
Dim param As New SqlParameter("@MyDateValue", Now)
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
```

The reason for this is string concatenation to build SQL is inherently unsafe due to the risk of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roryap... Its working perfectly fine. I messed up with the date in between and had problems with the Smtp and thought it was some thing to do with the code we edited.